# Generate man pages from doxygen style comments

Tags: doxygen, dynamically-generated, manpage

I have added doxygen comments all through-out my code. They are in this format:-

```
/**
 * @brief
 *  functionName() - function description
 *
 * @param[in]   variable_in - datatype
 *
 * @par Side-Effects: none
 *
 * @par    MT-Unsafe
 *
 * @return    target return type
 *
 */
```

My requirement is to generate man pages through these. How do I do this? There seems to be no straight-forward way to do this, as far as I have researched.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation about GENERATE_MAN

Comment: Where do I specify this option?

Comment: In the configuration file: Doxyfile

Comment: How silly of me. It's all there in the documentation, I guess I didn't find the correct page last time.

Thanks!